# How to echo custom html tag

Tags: php, html

In the following code:

```
<?php
$html='<p style="color:#eee;">
Test content 1.
</p>
<p dir="LTR" style="color:#f00;">
<span>Test content 2.</span>
</p>
<p style="color:#000;">
Test content 3.
</p>'
?>
```

I just want to echo dir = LTR

That is, as follows:

```
<?php
echo htmltag($html,'dir="LTR"');
?>
```

In fact the output is:

```
<p dir="LTR" style="color:#f00;">
Test content 2.
</p>
```

Comment: What is `htmltag` for a method? I don't find it in the php manual, could you link to it?

Comment: htmltag is not correct! For your information only. That i want to echo htmltag

Comment: do you want to insert `dir="LTR"` to all the html tags ?

Comment: No. dir="LTR" is only in one tag.

Comment: @MahdiHosseinpour so what are you trying to do ? your question is not clear, the function you are calling is not a built in php function. can you show that function if it is a custom function ?

Comment: @OmarAbbas. From $html I just want to echo <p> which has dir="LTR"

Comment: ok, I'll answer this question

Comment: @MahdiHosseinpour answered your question below, and please make sure to accept and up vote this answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php

$html='<p style="color:#eee;">
                Test content 1.
            </p>
            <p dir="LTR" style="color:#f00;">
                Test content 2.
            </p>
            <p style="color:#000;">
                Test content 3.
            </p>';

preg_match_all("/\<\w[^<>]*?\>([^<>]+?\<\/\w+?\>)?|\<\/\w+?\>/i", $html, $arr); 
foreach($arr[0] as $a){
    if (strpos($a, 'dir="LTR"') !== false) {
        echo $a;
    }
}

?>
```

**Explanation**

`preg_match_all("/\<\w[^<>]*?\>([^<>]+?\<\/\w+?\>)?|\<\/\w+?\>/i", $html, $arr);`

above line of code will create an array that will index each html tags and their content respectively.

```
foreach($arr[0] as $a){
    if (strpos($a, 'dir="LTR"') !== false) {
        echo $a;
    }
}
```

In the above loop we try to loop through all the tags and display only if that tag contains `dir="LTR"`

**Edit **
[Original web link](https://w-shadow.com/blog/2009/10/20/how-to-extract-html-tags-and-their-attributes-with-php/) for the function used below, hope it works for you.

```
<?php

/**
 * extract_tags()
 * Extract specific HTML tags and their attributes from a string.
 *
 * You can either specify one tag, an array of tag names, or a regular expression that matches the tag name(s). 
 * If multiple tags are specified you must also set the $selfclosing parameter and it must be the same for 
 * all specified tags (so you can't extract both normal and self-closing tags in one go).
 * 
 * The function returns a numerically indexed array of extracted tags. Each entry is an associative array
 * with these keys :
 *  tag_name    - the name of the extracted tag, e.g. "a" or "img".
 *  offset      - the numberic offset of the first character of the tag within the HTML source.
 *  contents    - the inner HTML of the tag. This is always empty for self-closing tags.
 *  attributes  - a name -> value array of the tag's attributes, or an empty array if the tag has none.
 *  full_tag    - the entire matched tag, e.g. '<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>'. This key 
 *                will only be present if you set $return_the_entire_tag to true.      
 *
 * @param string $html The HTML code to search for tags.
 * @param string|array $tag The tag(s) to extract.                           
 * @param bool $selfclosing Whether the tag is self-closing or not. Setting it to null will force the script to try and make an educated guess. 
 * @param bool $return_the_entire_tag Return the entire matched tag in 'full_tag' key of the results array.  
 * @param string $charset The character set of the HTML code. Defaults to ISO-8859-1.
 *
 * @return array An array of extracted tags, or an empty array if no matching tags were found. 
 */
function extract_tags( $html, $tag, $selfclosing = null, $return_the_entire_tag = false, $charset = 'ISO-8859-1' ){

    if ( is_array($tag) ){
        $tag = implode('|', $tag);
    }

    //If the user didn't specify if $tag is a self-closing tag we try to auto-detect it
    //by checking against a list of known self-closing tags.
    $selfclosing_tags = array( 'area', 'base', 'basefont', 'br', 'hr', 'input', 'img', 'link', 'meta', 'col', 'param' );
    if ( is_null($selfclosing) ){
        $selfclosing = in_array( $tag, $selfclosing_tags );
    }

    //The regexp is different for normal and self-closing tags because I can't figure out 
    //how to make a sufficiently robust unified one.
    if ( $selfclosing ){
        $tag_pattern = 
            '@<(?P<tag>'.$tag.')           # <tag
                        (?P<attributes>\s[^>]+)?       # attributes, if any
                        \s*/?>                   # /> or just >, being lenient here 
                        @xsi';
    } else {
        $tag_pattern = 
            '@<(?P<tag>'.$tag.')           # <tag
                        (?P<attributes>\s[^>]+)?       # attributes, if any
                        \s*>                 # >
                        (?P<contents>.*?)         # tag contents
                        </(?P=tag)>               # the closing </tag>
                        @xsi';
    }

    $attribute_pattern = 
        '@
                (?P<name>\w+)                         # attribute name
                \s*=\s*
                (
                        (?P<quote>[\"\'])(?P<value_quoted>.*?)(?P=quote)    # a quoted value
                        |                           # or
                        (?P<value_unquoted>[^\s"\']+?)(?:\s+|$)           # an unquoted value (terminated by whitespace or EOF) 
                )
                @xsi';

    //Find all tags 
    if ( !preg_match_all($tag_pattern, $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER | PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE ) ){
        //Return an empty array if we didn't find anything
        return array();
    }

    $tags = array();
    foreach ($matches as $match){

        //Parse tag attributes, if any
        $attributes = array();
        if ( !empty($match['attributes'][0]) ){ 

            if ( preg_match_all( $attribute_pattern, $match['attributes'][0], $attribute_data, PREG_SET_ORDER ) ){
                //Turn the attribute data into a name->value array
                foreach($attribute_data as $attr){
                    if( !empty($attr['value_quoted']) ){
                        $value = $attr['value_quoted'];
                    } else if( !empty($attr['value_unquoted']) ){
                        $value = $attr['value_unquoted'];
                    } else {
                        $value = '';
                    }

                    //Passing the value through html_entity_decode is handy when you want
                    //to extract link URLs or something like that. You might want to remove
                    //or modify this call if it doesn't fit your situation.
                    $value = html_entity_decode( $value, ENT_QUOTES, $charset );

                    $attributes[$attr['name']] = $value;
                }
            }

        }

        $tag = array(
            'tag_name' => $match['tag'][0],
            'offset' => $match[0][1], 
            'contents' => !empty($match['contents'])?$match['contents'][0]:'', //empty for self-closing tags
            'attributes' => $attributes, 
        );
        if ( $return_the_entire_tag ){
            $tag['full_tag'] = $match[0][0];            
        }

        $tags[] = $tag;
    }

    return $tags;
}

$html='<p>
                    Test content 1.
                </p>
                <p dir="LTR" style="color:#f00;">
                    <span>
                        Test content 2.
                    </span>
                </p>
                <p style="color:#000;">
                    Test content 3.
                </p>';

$tag = 'p';

$result = extract_tags( $html, $tag, $selfclosing = null, $return_the_entire_tag = false, $charset = 'ISO-8859-1' );

foreach($result as $key1=>$res){
    foreach($res['attributes'] as $key2=>$attribute){
        if ($key2 == 'dir'){
            if($attribute == 'LTR'){
                echo $res['contents'];
            }
        }
    }

}



?>
```

Comment: Can " $a = $b " be replaced with " echo $a " ?

Comment: I would suggest using `` Instead of `''`

Comment: @MahdiHosseinpour I will edit my answer and try to give some explanation for the code.

Comment: @OmarAbbas I think your code will only echo the text. I want to echo the output in html.

Comment: @MahdiHosseinpour yes.

Comment: @OmarAbbas I want to spend html and support Farsi. Because it may be inside `<p>` another tag like `<span>`.

Comment: `<p dir="LTR" style="color:#f00;"><span>Text</span></p>`

Comment: @OmarAbbas On my site, it only echo `<p dir = "LTR" style = "text-align: justify;">`. Does not echo content inside it, which is `<span>`.

Comment: @MahdiHosseinpour I understand, this won't work. I'll try to find a solution that works for you.

Comment: @OmarAbbas Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have found a nice function but, can you explain what is your purpose for this ? what are you trying to achieve by this ?

Comment: I just want to echo certain content from the database.